# PS command does not show running process

Tags: shell, unix, sed, ksh, ps

I have very long running shell script ( runs more than 24 hours) . 
It is very simple script. It just reads xml file from a dir and perform `sed` operation of the content of the file. There are 1 millions xml files in the dir.

My script name is like runDataManipulation.sh

When I run following command

```
ps -ef | grep "runDa*"
```

then sometime I see my process as

```
username 34535 1 48 11:42:01  - 224:22 /usr/bin/ksh ./runDataManipulation.sh
```

But if I run exactly same command after couple of seconds then I don't see above process at all.

As my process is running all the time so I expect that `ps` command to show the process all the time.

If I do `grep` on the process id of my script like ..

```
ps -ef | grep 34535
```

then sometime I see result like

```
username 34535 1 51 11:42:01  - 229:22 [ksh]
```

sometime I see result like

```
username 45678 34535 0 14:12:11  - 0:0 [sed]
```

My main questions is that ... why do I not see my process when I `grep` for my process using script name. I am using `AIX 6.1`.

Comment: It would be useful to see the contents of the `runDataManipulation.sh` script as it must be doing something to get it's process listing to change. It's notable that on AIX you can modify the contents of `*argv[]` (in C parlance) and your changes will be reflected in the process listing. Not all Unix OS's allow this.

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like one script is spawning off your script in another process.

If you look at the results of your ps command below the first line is showing the process id of 34535, this is the main id (say parent id).

username 34535 1 51 11:42:01 - 229:22 [ksh]

This process in turn is firing off another process, this can be seen below, notice the id of the parent process (34535) is mentioned in the line below, the first number is the main process Id and the second number is the calling process.

username 45678 34535

If you changed your ps command to include the sed command you should always see some results if your scripts are still running!

Comment: Thanks. I fully understand that my script spawns a new process for the sed command  and the new sed process will have have a new pid  and its ppid (parent pid) will have my main script pid ( 34535). But my parent process does not dies when it spawns new process  so I would always expect that my main process(runDataManipulation.sh) to appear in the ps -ef output.  That was my main question.,, Why does my parent process not appear in the ps -ef command output when it is still running.